# Redirecting to initial view controller

Tags: ios, storyboard, appdelegate

Is there any way to redirect (push or perform segue etc.) to initial view controller aka rootViewController from `appdelegate` class? I am using `stroryboard` btw.
Any answers are appreciated.

**UP.** I am not using navigation controller.

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationController?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305636/how-to-perform-segue-in-appdelegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Comment: Perfect solution. I was looking for it for a long time =)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest nesting all your navigation stack under a `UINavigationController`, then it would be as easy as invoking the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` method.

Comment: Tnx. I know that way, but I need find some feature without using nav controller :(

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationController popToRootViewController methods takes you there, if you're using UINav controller.

Other way you can try out: self.window.rootViewController is a reference that might useful.

Comment: So the problem, is how to redirect to that self.window.rootViewController =)

Answer (score 0):

By Using Swift 4.2

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let window: UIWindow? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window)!
window?.rootViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
```

Working Perfect...